# Entity Framework 4 - Use a single mapping table for all many-to-many relations

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, entity-relationship

I would like to map all many-to-may relations through a single table in my database.
Meaning that I have numerous tables (entities) that have various many-to-many relations. Instead of having a separate mapping table for every relation I would like to use one "master mapping" table having to columns: End1Id & End2Id.

Don't ask why ;) It's required by my customer...

How would I set this up in the model designer, or do I have to edit the edmx xml directly....or is it just not possible?

Thanx for your help!

Comment: I'd go back to your customer and ask why - this isn't a very good data design.

Comment: That is crappy requirement ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a scenario you can't have explicit foreign keys, because a table like this normally has at least three rows:

1. PK of table 1
2. PK of table 2
3. Type of mapping, **which specifies the exact tables to use**.

Because of that, you can just create a table in EF, but it will also have no connections to other tables and you will have to do the joins manually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware that I can't use foreign key in this scenario. But I do want to have relations in the EF model so that I don't have to join manually. Isn't there a way to edit the edmx file an "bend" all relations to the same table?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set this Master Mappings table manually. The designer doesn't do it for you automatically.

However - if denormalized entities are what you are looking for, better have those denormalized in DB level rather than in EF/code level.

Comment: What we are trying to achieve is a "hybrid" data structure. We have entities with relations at design time. In addition to that we have an association table that defines dynamic relations between entities. These additional relations can be configured at run time and do not require us to deploy a new version of the software. These relations obviously use ONE mapping table and they are all many-to-many (no worries about cardinality!). To unify the model, I would like to use this mapping table even for the designed relations.